# Proof That Undefined Notions Exist

Tags: formal-languages

Undefined notions are terms which are to be understood intuitively, without precise definition. What's the proof of them being needed? I get that when we try to define a thing we need to use terms, which need to be defined too, an so on, but I want a formal proof, not an intuitive one.

Comment: Pretty much everything you need the [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) for, e.g. nonmeasurable sets, nonprincipal ultrafilters, cannot be defined explicitly -- only indirectly with the AC.

Comment: In order to get a _formal_ proof of anything, you have to specify particular axioms and definitions you want it proved from. Some of it can perhaps be filled in by answerers, but it will be _essential_ that you give some clear definition of "needed" if you want to see proofs about it.